# how I could collect data from variable for a while in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, while-loop, collect

for example this code

Im trying to use  a title for collect data in 2d array but I need to do this with a loop but I  dont know how ?

this is my code

```
 (1..8).collect{
    ["date":f2[it].split(";")[0],'product':f2[it].split(";")[1], 'quant':f2[it].split(";")[2], 'weight':f2[it].split(";")[3], 'price':f2[it].split(";")[4],
  }
```

reduce to something like this

this is the code that Im trying to use in groovylang

but not work I dont know what is the problem

```
st="date;product;quant;weight;price"
x=0
 (1..8).collect{
    [8.times {st[x]:f2[it].split(";")[x],; x=x+1}}
```

please help me

Comment: Please spend sometime writing your question with minimal required description. How do you expect people to spend time on your question and provide answers as well?

Comment: yes ; i will do

Comment: Still got no idea what your trying to do and what you expect the result to be

Comment: Do you have a CSV file with a header row defining the names and you want to create a list of maps from it, where the keys in the maps are the headlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, we are talking some kind of CSV file here, this eagerly creates a list of maps with the data:

```
def fauxcsv = ["a;b;c", "1;2;3", "42;93;666"]
def head = fauxcsv.first().split(";")
println fauxcsv.tail().take(8).collect{ // skip head, take up to 8 items
    [head, it.split(";")].transpose().collectEntries() // combine head and data and turn into map
}
// => [[a:1, b:2, c:3], [a:42, b:93, c:666]]
```